# loop through specific columns with criteria and break in r

Tags: r, loops, criteria

i want to achieve a few things as below:

1. check which column A001 is in, if found then return the column name but if none found then return 0
2. sometimes there are more than CHECK columns.. could have up to 20 and with additional columns.. how do i specify the loop to to loop through those columns
3. not sure looping is the correct way to do it but i feel like it is.. i'm open for other alternatives as well..

sample data and my trial as below

```
# sample
mydf <- data.frame(case = c(1, 2, 3),
                   id = c(10, 11, 12),
                   CHECK1 = c("A001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK2 = c("Z001", "K001", "C001"),
                   CHECK3 = c("Z001", "B001", "A001"))

for (i in 1:3) {
  
  # giving out position and column name
  mydf = mydf %>% mutate(CHECK_Pos = case_when(mydf[paste0("CHECK", i)] == "A001" ~ i * 1,
                                               TRUE ~ 0),
                         
                         CHECK_Name = case_when(mydf[paste0("CHECK", i)] == "A001" ~ paste0("CHECK", i),
                                               TRUE ~ "CHECK0"))
  
}
```

this doesn't work as it will always loop through all columns to the end for all rows, but i don't know how to stop the loop whenever there's a match.
my ideal output is:
CHECK_Pos = c(1, 0, 3)
CHECK_Name = c("CHECK1", "CHECK0", "CHECK3")
please help?? thank you very much in advance~~!!

**follow up question:**
what if i have more columns but i don't really know how to change the codes

## sample

```
mydf <- data.frame(case = c(1, 2, 3),
                   id = c(10, 11, 12),
                   CHECK1 = c("A001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK2 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK3 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK4 = c("Z001", "B001", "A001"),
                   CHECK5 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"))
```

modification trial:

```
get_colname = function(df, value) {
  ind = which(sapply(mydf[3:7], function (x) {value %in% x}))
  
  name = names(mydf[3:7])
  name[-ind] = "CHECK0"
  
  pos = 1:3
  pos[-ind] = 0
  
  if (length(ind) == 0) {
    name = rep("CHECK0", 3)
    pos = rep(0, 3)
  }
  df = df %>%
    mutate(check_pos = pos,
           check_name = name)
  
  return(df)
}

get_colname(mydf, "A001")
```

and then i will get the error: Error: Column `check_name` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 5

i know is probably this "name = names(mydf[3:7])" causing the error.. but i don't know what to change to.. please help~

Comment: Change pos = 1:5 name = rep("CHECK0", 5)
    pos = rep(0, 5) return(data.frame(pos, name)) remove this line df = df %>%
    mutate(check_pos = pos,
           check_name = name)

Comment: hi @Stacker.. thanks for replying but this will lead to 2 problems.. ><where it is showing 1) another dataframe 2) with vertical alignment where my data is horizontal alignment.. i need them to be together.. showing PRLCDE1, PRLCDE0, PRLCDE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop if there's a match using `break` inside an `if` statement, but I can't see where to put that in your code. Anyway, this works. Briefly, it checks if the value is `%in%` each column.

```
get_colname=function(df, value) {
  ind=which(sapply(mydf[3:5], function (x) {value %in% x}))
  name=names(mydf[3:5])
  name[-ind]="CHECK0"
  pos=1:3
  pos[-ind]=0
  if (length(ind)==0) {
    name=rep("CHECK0", 3)
    pos=rep(0,3)
  }
  df=mutate(df, check_pos=pos, check_name=name)
  return(df)
}

get_colname(mydf, "A001")
  case id CHECK1 CHECK2 CHECK3 check_pos check_name
1    1 10   A001   Z001   Z001         1     CHECK1
2    2 11   B001   K001   B001         0     CHECK0
3    3 12   C001   C001   A001         3     CHECK3

get_colname(mydf, "D001")
  case id CHECK1 CHECK2 CHECK3 check_pos check_name
1    1 10   A001   Z001   Z001         0     CHECK0
2    2 11   B001   K001   B001         0     CHECK0
3    3 12   C001   C001   A001         0     CHECK0
```

Comment: thank you so much @stacker but what if i have a follow up questions?? say for example same set of data but with additional CHECK columns.. i'll update my questions there.. because i'm not sure whether to change accordingly..  can you please help?? thanks~!!!